# Bootstrap requires non-existing version of popper

Tags: bootstrap-4, npm-install, popper.js

My package.json contains:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
```

on install the warning is:

> bootstrap@4.1.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.0

however the ["latest" version of popper.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper) is 1.0.1

wtf?!? are there two different 'flavors' of popper?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You checked the wrong package. It is **`popper.js`**, not `popper`.

So, to install run:

```
npm install popper.js
```

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js)'s the package on npm.

Comment: Yeah, this confused me by a lot too. Most solutions don't mention this important aspect